# Chromedriver ignores LeaveBrowserRunning option

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a very hard time tracking down a "unexpected alert open" test failure. The failure happens when running the test from the command line with MSTest but does not when I run from VS. The version of chromedriver is the same for each (2.16). I'm writing the tests in VB.Net 4.5.

If I could see the text of the alert I could start to troubleshoot what's going on, but as soon as an alert pops up that test and all following tests immediately fail and chromedriver exits. I'm setting the property as such:

```
Dim chromeOptions = New ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.LeaveBrowserRunning = True
Dim driver as ChromeDriver = New ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)
```

Am I failing to understand what LeaveBrowserRunning is supposed to do? Even when I run the test suite in Visual Studio and it runs all the way through successfully the chrome window exits immediately, so the problem doesn't appear to be the uncaught exception.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I´m issuing exactly the opposite, no matter what I set it always leave the browser running